# Wordcount program is stuck in hadoop-2.3.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I installed hadoop-2.3.0 and tried to run wordcount example 
But it starts the job and sits idle

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.3.0.jar    wordcount /myprg outputfile1
14/04/30 13:20:40 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/04/30 13:20:51 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/04/30 13:20:53 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
14/04/30 13:21:02 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1398885280814_0004
14/04/30 13:21:07 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1398885280814_0004
14/04/30 13:21:09 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ubuntu:8088/proxy/application_1398885280814_0004/
14/04/30 13:21:09 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1398885280814_0004
```

**The url to track the job: application_1398885280814_0004/**
[image]
[image]

For previous versions I did nt get such an issue. I was able to run hadoop wordcount in previous version.
I followed [these steps](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/hadoop-installation-for-beginners.html) for installing hadoop-2.3.0

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you looked at the `url to track the job: http://ubuntu:8088/proxy/application_1398885280814_0003/`?

Comment: @climbage : I updated my question with screenshot of tracking url

Comment: What else do you have going on in your cluster?  Do you have any active nodes in the `Nodes` section of the tracking URL?  Your job is not being assigned which leads me to believe you don't have any nodes.

Comment: Yes I have .I am running my cluster in pseudomode and jobtracker list my Live node as 1 and no dead node is also shown .so for sure my node is up. But why is it not executing?

Comment: Its hard to tell without more information from the resource manager logs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the exact same situation a while back while switching to YARN. Basically there was the concept of `task slots` in MRv1 and `containers` in MRv2. Both of these differ very much in how the tasks are scheduled and run on the nodes.

The reason that your job is stuck is that it is unable to find/start a `container`. If you go into the full logs of `Resource Manager/Application Master` etc daemons, you may find that it is doing nothing after it starts to allocate a new container.

To solve the problem, you have to tweak your memory settings in `yarn-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml`. While doing the same myself, I found [this](http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide) and [this](http://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/) tutorials especially helpful. I would suggest you to try with the very basic memory settings and optimize them later on. First check with a word count example then go on to other complex ones.

Comment: I went across exactly same problem but solution did not work for me

Comment: this solution didn't work for me. Still facing the same issue

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue.I added the following property to my yarn-site.xml and it solved the issue.

```
 <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>Hostname-of-your-RM</value>
        <description>The hostname of the RM.</description>
    </property>
```

Without the resource manager host name things go awry in the multi-node set up as each node would then default to trying to find a local resource manager  and would never announce its resources to the master node. So your Map Reduce execution request probably didn't find any mappers in which to run because the request was being sent to the master and the master didn't know about the slave slots.

Reference : http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide/

Comment: I changed yarn-site.xml as mentioned in above link and it worked. Thanks for answer

Comment: what would be my "Hostname-of-your-RM"? 
is it something from host file in windows?

Comment: Nothing changed for me. I still face the same issue on my Windows machine.