# Hadoop 2.3.0 wordcount runs forever

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to test my hadoop installation by running a wordcount job. My problem is that the job gets stuck at ACCEPTED state and seems to run forever. I am using hadoop 2.3.0 and tried fix the problem by following an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397763/wordcount-program-is-stuck-in-hadoop-2-3-0) but it didn't work for me.

This is what I have:

```
C:\hadoop-2.3.0>yarn jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.3.0.jar wordcount /data/test.txt /data/output
15/03/15 15:36:07 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at/0.0.0.0:8032
15/03/15 15:36:09 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/03/15 15:36:10 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/03/15 15:36:10 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_14 26430101974_0001
15/03/15 15:36:11 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_14 26430101974_0001
15/03/15 15:36:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://Agata-PC:8088/proxy/application_1426430101974_0001/
15/03/15 15:36:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1426430101974_0001
```

This is my `mapred-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
   <value>yarn</value>
</property>
 <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:9001</value>
</property>
   <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir</name>
    <value>/user</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.history.server.http.address</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:51111</value>
    <description>Http address of the history server</description>
    <final>false</final>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx768m</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>The number of virtual cores required for each map task.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>The number of virtual cores required for each map task.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
    <description>Larger resource limit for maps.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx768m</value>
    <description>Heap-size for child jvms of maps.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
    <description>Larger resource limit for reduces.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx768m</value>
    <description>Heap-size for child jvms of reduces.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

And this is my `yarn-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>128</value>
        <description>Minimum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource Manager.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <description>The minimum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests lower than this won't take effect, and the specified value will get allocated the minimum.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>2</value>
        <description>The maximum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests higher than this won't take effect, and will get capped to this value.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>2048</value>
        <description>Physical memory, in MB, to be made available to running containers</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
        <value>4</value>
        <description>Number of CPU cores that can be allocated for containers.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordcount program is stuck in hadoop-2.3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397763/wordcount-program-is-stuck-in-hadoop-2-3-0)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, please somebody help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try restarting your hadoop's processes or clusters? There might be some works still running.

May be it will be helpful to see the log by following the url of the job or by going through the hadoop url.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I tried to run the job a couple of times and it keeps getting stuck there.

Comment: Can you please show me the logs of the jobs you're running, including the result from jps, just in case.

Comment: This is what I can see in the overview. `User:  Agata
Name:  word count
Application Type:  MAPREDUCE
State:  ACCEPTED
FinalStatus:  UNDEFINED
Started:  15-Mar-2015 20:23:31
Elapsed:  14mins, 33sec
Tracking URL:  UNASSIGNED
Diagnostics:`

Comment: On the left side of the page, checkout the Tools, then local logs, /userlogs, and find the jobs name that match yours. If possible, you may need to copy the content from every container inside the jobs logs.

Also, please run the 'jps' command in the terminal and copy the result.

Comment: In local logs there is nothing except one authentication link that leads to a blank page :(

Comment: Did you copy from local to HDFS? I mean, is the path "/data/test.txt" really exist.



Try "yarn dfs -ls /data" (sry if it's mistyped, i'm not sure about the exact command).



Also, please run the jps command like this http://puu.sh/gBUf9/2e57c5b9f0.jpg
I would like to see the result from both jps and dfs -ls

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and this is my ```jps``` command output:

```22560 NameNode
22740 ResourceManager
22964 DataNode
23860 Jps
6572 RunJar```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issue earlier, you might have a infinite loop in mapper or reducer . Check if your reducer is properly handling iterable.

Comment: I ran the default jar file provided by hadoop itself, which is the ```share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.2.4.jar``` file. So, there is no chance of code getting wrong.