# MapReduce job not working in HADOOP-2.6.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run wordcount example

Here is the code

```
   import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

I see something like

```
    15/06/05 02:32:04 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/06/05 02:32:04 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/06/05 02:32:04 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
15/06/05 02:32:05 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
15/06/05 02:32:05 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1433448750700_0003
15/06/05 02:32:05 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1433448750700_0003
15/06/05 02:32:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1433448750700_0003/
15/06/05 02:32:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1433448750700_0003
```

I came across this post [Wordcount program is stuck in hadoop-2.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397763/wordcount-program-is-stuck-in-hadoop-2-3-0) 
But solution did not work for me

Comment: Please add the job class, map and reducer classes, to help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this issue. I needed to add the following property in yarn-site.xml

```
 <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>Hostname-of-your-RM</value>
        <description>The hostname of the RM.</description>
    </property>
```

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Hadoop 2.6 and using mapred package. I think the new package names include mapreduce. Please follow the example [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) to run correct version. Also you can use [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269922/hadoop-mapred-vs-hadoop-mapreduce) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job) for understanding the differences between the two

Comment: I treid it .Same problem

Comment: Are you running in cluster or local workspace. If local, can you add any debug statements and see, if you get any exceptions

Comment: Where to get debug statements?

Comment: I mean in java code and also the logs mentioned in the post you referenced

Comment: Even I am not sure, where is it failing, due to absence of exception. One thing I obeserved, is it is suggesting to use Tool Runner interface. This is another way of writing job. Can you try [that](https://github.com/aamend/hadoop-mapreduce/blob/master/sandbox/src/main/java/com/aamend/hadoop/mapreduce/sandbox/ToolImplementation.java) and see if it works. Also, if your mapper is picked up, then it should show smoething like this "mapreduce.Job: map 0% reduce 0%   mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 0%"

Comment: Please post the results once resolved and let me know, if the suggestion helped. Happy coding.

Comment: Same problem,I think the problem is not with the code rather something is wrong with configuration